# Connect to local server on MAC from WINDOWS?

Tags: windows, macos

I am trying to connect to a .local server on my MacBook Pro from my Windows 8 desktop for testing.  Is this possible?

I can "access" it from computername.local/serverlocationfolder, but it messes up all of paths/styles since the install is using a CMS.

Is there something I can do from the Mac or PC side to make this possible?  Or will I have to install a local server (mysql, php, etc etc) on my Windows machine to test properly?

** I wanted to clarify that both of these machines are on the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add the domain name you are using to access your mac to your vhosts as a ServerAlias so that it points to the correct docroot. Don't forget to restart apache! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you find out the IP address of the machine you want to access and you have the appropriate ports open, you should be able to access any protocol from any machine.

You can use the IP address instead of the .local address anytime.